# Iterated integrations by parts using the fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Let $u \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{\Omega})$ and $\varphi$ be an eigenfunction of the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ in $\Omega$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. In what sense, if any, is it true that
$$\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda} \langle u, (-\Delta)^s\varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda} \langle(-\Delta)^s u, \varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \langle (-\Delta)^{2s} u, \varphi \rangle = ........?$$
Here $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the scalar product in $L^2(\Omega)$. In other words, is it true that we can integrate by parts using $(-\Delta)^su$, $(-\Delta)^{2s}u$ and so on even though their support is not compact anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot.

Formally, $\varphi$ is the eigenfunction of the unbounded operator $L_s$ on $L^2(\Omega)$, defined initially by
$$ L_s u(x) = (-\Delta)^s u(x) \qquad \text{for } x \in \Omega , $$
where $u \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (and it is understood that $u(x) = 0$ for $x \notin \Omega$), and then extended to an appropriate domain (e.g. by means of Friedrichs extension).

Now the key observation is that $L_s L_s$ is *not* equal to $L_{2s}$, unless $\Omega = \mathbb R^d$. Indeed, in $\Omega$ we have
$$ L_s L_s u = (-\Delta)^s (\mathbb 1_{\Omega} \times (-\Delta)^s u) , $$
while
$$ L_{2s} u = (-\Delta)^s (-\Delta)^s u , $$
and due to non-locality of $(-\Delta)^s$, the two are not equal.

For the above reasons, we have
$$ \langle u, \varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \langle u, L_s L_s \varphi \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \langle L_s L_s u, \varphi \rangle $$
(provided that $L_s u$ belongs to the domain of $L_s$, which is rarely the case!), and in general the right-hand side is not equal to $\lambda^{-2} \langle (-\Delta)^{2s} u, \varphi \rangle$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then my real question is the following one: without this trick, how can we prove that $$U(t,x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi_k(x) \left( \langle u, \varphi_k \rangle \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)}{\sqrt{\lambda_k}} \right)$$ (which is the solution of the fractional wave equation in a regular open set $\Omega$ with initial velocity $u$ and zero initial displacement) is smooth in $x \in \Omega$ if $u$ is smooth?

Comment: I would have tried some energy conservation laws, but I never worked with the wave equation really. There are some recent works on this subject, e.g. [DOI:10.1515/fca-2018-0067](https://doi.org/10.1515/fca-2018-0067).